# Display command in xterm titlebar

Tags: bash, prompt, xterm, window-title

My Bash Prompt is currently setting the xterm titlebar using the following sequence:

```
PS1='\033]0;\u@\h>\w\007'
```

Is there an easy way to display the current command in the titlebar. For example, if I am tailing a file using `tail -f foo.log`, I want my titlebar to say `tail -f foo.log`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically, you need:

```
trap 'printf "\033]0;%s\007" "${BASH_COMMAND//[^[:print:]]/}"' DEBUG
```

at the end of your `.bashrc` or similar.  Took me a while to work this out -- see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command/5080670#5080670) for more information :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution simon! However, when adding this to my `.bashrc` after each command in my shell I get this output `0;%s@%s:%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}`. I assume that I can suppress this output by assigning the trap command to `PS1`? However, `PS1=trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG` does not work. It leads to the error `bash: echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007": command not found`.

Comment: BTW, I just fielded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407130/why-is-my-debug-trap-executed-w-content-redirected-in-echo-foo-echo-bar, asked presumably as a result of this advice being applied. The trap should be writing to stderr or to the TTY directly, not to stdout.

Comment: @orschiro, the advice to run the `trap` command *as a separate command*, not to assign it to PS1.

Answer (score 13):

<sub>(Inspired by [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command))</sub>

You can combine a couple bash tricks:

- If you trap a DEBUG signal, the handler is called before each command is executed
- The variable `$BASH_COMMAND` holds the currently executing command

So, trap DEBUG and have the handler set the title to `$BASH_COMMAND`:

```
trap 'printf "\033]0;%s\007" "${BASH_COMMAND//[^[:print:]]/}" >&2' DEBUG
```

This will keep the title changed until something else changes it, but as long as your `$PS1` stays the same it won't be a problem -- you start a command, the DEBUG handler changes the titlebar, and when the command finishes bash draws a new prompt and resets your titlebar again.

A useful tip found [here](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html) (also where that SU answer came from) is to include:

```
set -o functrace
```

This will make bash propagate the DEBUG trap to any subshells you start; otherwise the titlebar won't be changed in them

Comment: ha! same answer at exactly the same time!  +1 for handling subshells, but do you have any answer to the pipes problem?  (see my link to the SO question)

Comment: Doesn't work through `ssh`

Comment: Also "kills" the completion on "tab"

Comment: BTW, I just fielded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407130/why-is-my-debug-trap-executed-w-content-redirected-in-echo-foo-echo-bar, asked presumably as a result of this advice being applied. The trap should be writing to stderr or to the TTY directly, not to stdout.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to redirect to `/dev/tty` instead of stderr?

Answer (score 3):

I worked around my own solution from various posts around. This creates a title containing user, hostname, pwd, tty and currently executed command (for bash).

This looks like this (no command being executed):

```
.:[user@hostname:/home/user][pts/10]:.
```

And like this (executing a command):

```
.:[user@hostname:/home/user][pts/10] {tail -F /var/log/syslog}:.
```

Somewhere in the .bashrc, i extended PS1:

```
# set the terminals title. This is the "post-command" part,
# need to use a trap for pre-command (to add the command line to the title)
PS1+="\[\033]2;.:[\u@\h:\$PWD] [$(tty | cut -b 6-)]:.\007\]"
```

Adds the current command, using *history 1* and *trap*:

```
# set a fancy title (this is pre-command, in PS1 is after-command (to reset command)
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;.:[${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}] [$(tty | cut -b 6-)] {$(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")}:.\007"' DEBUG
```

Feel free to adopt to your needs.

Comment: BTW, I just fielded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407130/why-is-my-debug-trap-executed-w-content-redirected-in-echo-foo-echo-bar, asked presumably as a result of this advice being applied. The trap should be writing to stderr or to the TTY directly, not to stdout.

Comment: This is a quite good solution. The only downside is that the path won't update immediately after a `cd`, it will take one more command. Change `]2;` to `]0;` in order to set the icon name too.