# Set dynamic window title based on command input

Tags: bash, urxvt, window-title

I am looking for a way to dynamically set the urxvt window title based on the command input.

Let's take an example.

If I run `mplayer http://66.197.229.245:8082` in an urxvt window, I would like the  title of this window to be set to `mplayer http://66.197.229.245:8082` or even better `Terminal | mplayer`.

Or if I run `journalctl -b` I want the window title to be set to `Terminal | journalctl -b` or better `Terminal | journalctl`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 34):

Assuming you're using Bash as your shell you can set this variable.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;Terminal | mplayer\007"'
```

#### Examples

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

[image: ss #3]

#### Including the previous command in the title?

If you want a more elaborate title bar then you could use this method to dynamically set the currently running command in the title bar.

```
 $ trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG
```

#### Example

[image: ss #4]

[image: ss #5]

#### What you're looking for

To get what you want you'll need to do some work to parse out just the name of the executable, for example. So you'll have to make some decisions as to what part of the command you want. You could use `.. | awk '{print $1}'` to get the name of just the command.

#### Making it permanent

If you want to make this the default behavior via your `/etc/bashrc` or `$HOME/.bashrc` files, you'll likely need to follow [@simon's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5454/simon) suggestions in this SO Q&A titled: [Bash - Update terminal title by running a second command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command/5080670#5080670).

Simon's answer is as follows:

```
function settitle () {
    export PREV_COMMAND=${PREV_COMMAND}${@}
    echo -ne "\033]0;${PREV_COMMAND}\007"
    export PREV_COMMAND=${PREV_COMMAND}' | '
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND}';export PREV_COMMAND=""'

trap 'settitle "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
```

#### Redirection of output

As referenced in this SO Q&A titled: [Why is my DEBUG trap executed (w/ content redirected) in { echo foo; echo bar; } >file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48407412/33204)
 there's an answer there by @Charles Duffy which recommends redirecting output to `STDERR` or even better `/dev/tty`. His answer has good guidances on both these methods.

#### References

- [Display command in xterm titlebar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/display-command-in-xterm-titlebar)
- [Bash - Update terminal title by running a second command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command/5080670#5080670)
- [How to change the title of an xterm - 3. Dynamic titles](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#s3)

Comment: Thanks! I added `trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG` to my `.bashrc` to have this setting permanently. But now for every new urxvt terminal opened, I am getting this output: `0;%s@%s:%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
`. How can I suppress that?

Comment: Incorporate it into the prompt, `$PS1` would be the way to go.

Comment: I still cannot get it working. I tried assigning the `trap` command to a variable to add it to `PS1`. But how do I include the `DEBUG` in the variable assignment? For now my `.bashrc` looks as follows: http://pastebin.com/jqbE7W2Y

Comment: The funny looking output is because the `DEBUG` trap interferes with your `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is also trying to set the title. I worked around it with a bit of awk:

`trap 'echo $BASH_COMMAND |awk '\''!/\007/ {printf "\033]0;%s\007", $0}'\' DEBUG`

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how this works? I have a sneaking suspicion it's an escape code of some sort because `\033` is 0x1B, the escape indicator, but the `]` seems to indicate that it's console-specific, and I can't find the specific thing for Bash anywhere.

Comment: this works fine, however the trap breaks the use of coloring. see this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368935/updating-terminal-title-in-debug-trap-breaks-coloring

Comment: What terminal is this answer using ? (does it matter ?) How does this work, what are `\033]0;` and `\007` ? What does `trap` do which makes it helpful ? My `PROMPT_COMMAND` is "history -a" and I'd like to keep that part, how does that interact with your answer ? I find this answer easy to use, but hard to understand. (Looks tailored to help vampires :D)

Comment: BTW -- do we need the `export`s here? My expectation reading this code is that the variables are all used inside the same process, so just directly assigning them (without any explicit `declare` or `local` to prevent them from being shell-global) should suffice. (Happy to propose my own edit, if that works -- I believe my rep on this site is low enough that it would go in the review queue for your approval).

Comment: You'll need to make sure the `DEBUG` trap's output goes to `/dev/tty` to avoid causing bugs such as [Why is my DEBUG trap executed (w/ content redirected) in { echo foo; echo bar; } >file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407130/why-is-my-debug-trap-executed-w-content-redirected-in-echo-foo-echo-bar/48407412)