# Change tmux pane title to current folder name

Tags: tmux, window-title

By default, `tmux` sets the current *pane title* as the active command (ex:`vim`), even if `allow-rename` is `off`.

I want to change it to current folder name (`basename $PWD`).

Note that I do not want to dynamically change *window name*, since I sometimes use `rename-window` to set a custom name. In this case, the custom *window name* must persist.

Comment: Please clarify - when/how often do you want to change the pane title to the current folder name?  Only when you specifically request it (with a shortcut/key-binding/command)?  Or automatically, every time you `cd`?

Comment: Both. Every time I `cd` in a new dir, unless I had changed manually before.

Comment: I thought it was the window name you wanted to change manually?  The window name and pane title can be set independently of each other, using different escape sequences - see the [Names and Titles](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#NAMES_AND%20TITLES) section of the manual.

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to do: [Auto-update tmux status bar with active pane pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200589/auto-update-tmux-status-bar-with-active-pane-pwd/56653295#56653295)

Answer (score 3):

I do this by setting the title using an echo command and having it executed in the PROMPT_COMMAND environment variable. This comes up as a common question in other environments. Here's really good information on it.

[Set dynamic window title based on command input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104018/set-dynamic-window-title-based-on-command-input)