# Updating terminal title in debug trap breaks coloring

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

One can update terminal titles using the following syntax:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;TITLE\a"
```

where `\a` can also be `\007`. For dynamically updating the window title (on process start), I put the following in my `.bashrc` (inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104026/103120), simplified):

```
MY_TRAP_DEBUG() {
    echo -ne "\033]0; ${BASH_COMMAND} \a"
}
trap MY_TRAP_DEBUG DEBUG
```

Works fine. However, now when I want to print colored output:

```
echo -e "\033[0;33m SOME YELLOW TEXT"
```

, the output contains the command and results in ascii salad: see screenshot below.

[image]

1. Why?
2. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's two questions:

- why?

  escape sequences don't **nest**.  The title-sequence starts with `\033]0;` and ends with `\a` *or any other control sequence*.
- how do you fix this?

  You could *sanitize* the bash command by assigning that to a variable and using shell parameter substitution to remove escape characters (and `\a` ASCII BEL).  Just to make it look nice, you should also remove the square brackets (either **`[`** or **`]`**) after an escape character, as well as the numeric parameters that may follow.

Someone may provide an example using `BASH_REMATCH` (set as a side-effect of regex-matching) and use that as the *word* in a `${parameter##word}` substitution...

Comment: I ended up with something like `newTerminalTitle="${BASH_COMMAND//\\/\\\\}"`. the nesting totally makes sense, I havent thought of it.