# Set xterm title doesn't work over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I followed [unix s.e](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/display-command-in-xterm-titlebar) post and added the line,

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG
```

to my `.bashrc` file to set my last command as the terminal title. It works good on my ubuntu desktop machine.

When i add this line to my Centos server's `.bashrc` file and ssh into the Centos machine, it no longer works. SSH client terminal title has become blank and it prints all junk stuff on my console after every command,

```
Last login: Sun Jun  7 21:28:29 2015 from sk-box
]2;printf "k%s@%s:%s]0;printf "k%s@%s:%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"[root@sk-vbox ~]# cd
]2;printf "k%s@%s:%s]0;printf "k%s@%s:%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"[root@sk-vbox ~]# pwd
/root
]2;printf "k%s@%s:%s]0;printf "k%s@%s:%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"[root@sk-vbox ~]#
```

Is it possible to ensure that dynamic title works well over ssh?

Comment: SSH has no impact here. The problem could be something conflicting in your `.bashrc` or an old bash version that doesn't have a feature you rely on. What version of bash is the server running? What else is in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: thanks Gilles. my `.bashrc` & `/etc/bashrc/`  files are there at - https://github.com/madhavan020985/local-rc/tree/master/centos-7. I am suspicious, if this line that sets the `PROMPT_STRING` - https://github.com/madhavan020985/local-rc/blob/master/centos-7/etc-bashrc#L22 and if i changed it by mistake.

Comment: and bash version is - `4.2.46`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
> trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG
> ```

These two commands interfere with each other. `BASH_COMMAND` ends up containing the `PROMPT_COMMAND`, not the previously executed command. Since `PROMPT_COMMAND` contains a `\007` (a bell character after backslash expansion), which is the end marker for the title text, the result is quite messy — you see the string after that from `PROMPT_COMMAND` before your prompt, and the bell rings when the second `\007` is printed. You're also performing an extra level of backslash expansion in `BASH_COMMAND`.

Replace your DEBUG trap by a more robust one that takes care of not printing special characters:

```
trap 'printf "\033]0;%s\007" "${BASH_COMMAND//[^[:print:]]/}"' DEBUG
```

Comment: i would never have cracked this in my life, if it is not for you, Gilles....